# Unsupervised CNN keras model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I am new with using unsupervised CNN model in python. I am trying to use CNN model for image classification with unsupervised spectrogram input images. Each image is of size 523 width and 393 height. And I have tried the following code

```
    X_data = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/train/*.png")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    image_resized = misc.imresize(image, (523,393))
    image_resi = misc.imresize(image_resized, (28, 28))
    assert image_resized.shape == (523,393, 3), "img %s has shape %r" % (myFile, image_resized.shape)
    X_data.append (image_resi)

X_datatest = []
files = glob.glob ("C:/test/*.png")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    image_resized = misc.imresize(image, (523,393))
    image_resi = misc.imresize(image_resized, (28, 28))
    assert image_resized.shape == (523,393, 3), "img %s has shape %r" % (myFile, image_resized.shape)
    X_datatest.append (image_resi)

X_data = np.array(X_data)
X_datatest = np.array(X_datatest)    

X_data= X_data.astype('float32') / 255.
X_datatest = X_datatest.astype('float32') / 255.
X_data = np.reshape(X_data, (len(X_data), 28, 28, 3))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
X_datatest = np.reshape(X_datatest, (len(X_datatest), 28, 28, 3))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

noise_factor = 0.5
x_train_noisy = X_data + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=X_data.shape) 
x_test_noisy = X_datatest + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=X_datatest.shape) 

x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)
x_test_noisy = np.clip(x_test_noisy, 0., 1.)


input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (7, 7, 32)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'] )

autoencoder.fit(x_train_noisy, X_data,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=128,
                verbose = 2,
                validation_data=(x_test_noisy, X_datatest),
                callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/tb', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False)])
```

I have tried to make noise and fed it as labels because i didn't have labels because this is an unsupervised spectrogram data. But the output is 33% only for the accuracy. I don't know why. Can anyone help me with this and try to make me understand the numbers of filters, kernels and the resize with 28*28 based on what? And why we just use the image size which is here 523 width and 393 height?